# Custom Role Based Authorization in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, user-roles

I am developing a web application where I have React as my Frontend and Spring boot as the Backend REST API. I have authentication mechanism setup where user can login with email and password. My application will be used by a group of people for a company. The admin user will login initially and sends invites to other people in the group with predefined access privileges available in the application. How can I implement this type of role based access in spring boot.

I gone across Spring security for role based access, but I didn't find how to create custom fine grained roles based on our web application. Please someone help just to give me the path I need to go.

P.S: I want to implement the way AWS or other cloud providers implement there IAM roles to assign it to different users in their organization but not as complex but a similar functionality

Comment: `but I didn't find how to create custom fine grained roles based on our web application` what did you tried? What did you find online and what not?

Comment: There are plenty of articles online and sample apps on github. Have you googled at all?

Comment: https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-blog-app is one with basic examples

Comment: The roles I find available are ROLE_USER, ROLE_EDITOR and ROLE_ADMIN in spring boot. I didn't find how to create custom roles with specific permissions.

Comment: The repo shared also uses ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER that's it. What if i want more constraining permssions, how can I do that??  @gtiwari333

Comment: See gt.app.modules.user.AppPermissionEvaluatorService in the project.

Comment: You will need AppPermissionEvaluatorService.hasPermission and can use it on your controller methods as `@PreAuthorize("@permEvaluator.hasAccess(`

Comment: You also need to add a separate Permission table, link that to User and check if user has permission or not in `AppPermissionEvaluatorService.hasPermission` method

Comment: AppPermissionEvaluatorService is just a starter code. You can add your custom logic as required

Comment: Can you suggest the article or documentation where I can find custom implementation

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/ the official spring security doc has all you need

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-access this to be precise

Comment: I followed th same in my test project